# Get name of child in Treeview after drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, treeview

I used the search function, but couldn't find the answer. I'm working on a school / internship project.

I have a drag and drop function. `String`s go from a `ListBox` to a `TreeView`. the structure of the `TreeView` is unknown. I only want to know the childs.

I would like to do:

1) Put all motors and sensors in the `ListBox` (from a motor and sensor list) > This is no problem

2) Drag f.e. a sensor to the `TreeView`. The sensor disappears from the `ListBox`. > This is also no problem.

3) Update the `ListBox`. During the drag and drop it is possible that a new sensor or motor is created. I would like to have all sensors and actors in the `ListBox`, exept the ones who already are in the `TreeView`. Here is a problem. I cant find the childs in the `TreeView`.

I can find the child that i added manually by `treeview.Nodes.Add("P5")`. But I cannot find the drag and drop childs in the `TreeView`. So, I can find P5 bus can't find FSA after drag and drop.

Does anyone know the difference between a drag and drop node and a manual node?
How could i find the drag and drop childs.

edit: I think I'm only searching in the first layer of the `treeview` . And not in the layers after that. No solution yet.

Thanks!

```
private void treeViewDrop_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode nodeToDropIn = treeViewDrop.GetNodeAt(treeViewDrop.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    if (nodeToDropIn == null) { return; }
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(String));
    if (data == null) { return; }
    nodeToDropIn.Nodes.Add(data.ToString());

    // Data (string) to HLF of motor , textbox
    foreach (Sensor mySensor in sensorlist.Where(sensor => sensor.TAG == data.ToString()))
    {
        string treeviewpath = nodeToDropIn.FullPath.ToString();
        string treeviewpath1 = treeviewpath.Replace(@"\", ".");
        mySensor.Higherlevelfunction = treeviewpath1 + "." + data.ToString();
    }

    // Data (string) to HLF of motor, textbox
    foreach (Motor mymotor in motorlist.Where(motor => motor.TAG == data.ToString()))
    {
        string treeviewpath = nodeToDropIn.FullPath.ToString();
        string treeviewpath1 = treeviewpath.Replace(@"\", ".");
        mymotor.Higherlevelfunction = treeviewpath1 + "." + data.ToString();
    }

    // Refresh equipment
    LoadPropsFlowSensor();
    LoadPropsPressureSensor();
    LoadPropsLevelSensor();
    loadPropsMotor();


    listBoxDrag.Items.Remove(data);
    treeViewDrop.ExpandAll();
}

private void listBoxDrag_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void treeViewDrop_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void listBoxDrag_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    listBoxDrag.DoDragDrop(this.listBoxDrag.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void treeViewDrop_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        // Pop up screen. Write here node name of group
        string nodename = "";
        nodename = Interaction.InputBox("Supply new node name", "New node", "", -1, -1);
        if (nodename == "") { return; }
        if (treeViewDrop.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            treeViewDrop.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nodename);
            treeViewDrop.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove selected node 
    if (treeViewDrop.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        treeViewDrop.SelectedNode.Remove();
    }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Refresh listbox with all sensors and actors who are not in the treeview.
    Refreshlistbox();
}

List<String> stringlist1 = new List<String>();
List<String> stringlist2 = new List<String>();
private void Refreshlistbox()
{

    listBoxDrag.Items.Clear();
    stringlist1.Clear();

    foreach (Sensor mysensor in sensorlist)
    {
        stringlist1.Add(mysensor.TAG);
    }
    foreach (Motor mymotor in motorlist)
    {
        stringlist1.Add(mymotor.TAG);
    }

    stringlist2.Clear();

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewDrop.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text.Equals("FSA"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes, found FSA");
        }
    }
    treeViewDrop.Nodes.Add("P5");

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewDrop.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text.Equals("P5"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes,  found P5");
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done");

    var firstNotSecond = stringlist1.Except(stringlist2).ToList();
    foreach (String mystring in firstNotSecond)
    {
        listBoxDrag.Items.Add(mystring);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
    private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        // Print the node.  
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(treeNode.Text);
        stringlist2.Add(treeNode.Text);
         // Print each node recursively.  
        foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            PrintRecursive(tn);
        }
    }

    // Call the procedure using the TreeView.  
    private void CallRecursive(TreeView treeView)
    {
        // Print each node recursively.  
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
        foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            PrintRecursive(n);
        }
    }
```